# How can I show that there is a monotonically increasing sequence $\{n_j\}_{j=0}^\infty$ such that $\{\sin(n_j)\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

How can I show that there is a monotonically increasing sequence $\{n_j\}_{j=0}^\infty$ such that $\{\sin(n_j)\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is convergent?

From the convergence definition I know that if $\{\sin(n_j)\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is convergent, say $\{\sin(n_j)\}_{j=1}^\infty\to l$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a natural number $N$ such that
$$
n_j\geq N\Rightarrow |\sin(n_j)-l|<\epsilon
$$
$|\sin(n_j)-l|<\epsilon$ can be written as $l-\epsilon<\sin(n_j)<l+\epsilon$ and so $\arcsin(l-\epsilon)<n_j<\arcsin(l+\epsilon)$  and that tells me that I need $N>\arcsin(l-\epsilon)$. If I want to show that there is a monotonically increasing sequence $\{n_j\}_{j=0}^\infty$, I need to show that $n_{j+1}>n_j$ or $n_{j+1}-n_{j}>0$.

Comment: You can show this by setting $n_j=n\cdot \pi$...

Comment: @5xum: I am not sure how.

Comment: Well, if $n_j = j\cdot \pi$, then $\{n_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence and $\{\sin(n_j)\}_{j=1}^\infty$ converges (because it's a sequence of zeros), so the statement is proven.

Comment: @5xum: That was too easy. I think I though the problem was so hard and then I spent a lot of time on it. Thanks.

Comment: @AnonymousStudent Of course you are asked to find some **integer valued** such sequence $(n_j)$... It is not clear whether 5xum's pair of comments was posted seriously or in jest but in any case, you should definitely be more careful with the statements of the exercises you are asked to solve.

Comment: @Did: How do you know that $\{n_j\}$ is integer valued? the question does not say that $\{\sin(n_j)\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a subsequence.

Comment: I do not *know* it but I *guess* it, because without this hypothesis the exercise is absurd, as witnessed below, and because, with this hypothesis, it is a classics. Did you at least check in your notes and/or with your TA before posting your comment?

Comment: @Did: I posted the verbatim question, there was no other extra information that I did not provide. So if the question does not talk about subsequence, we can not make any conclusion. I will ask my instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weierstrass–Bolzano Theorem says that any bounded sequence has a convergent sub-sequence. Since $(\sin{n})$ is bounded, this implies that there exists a strictly increasing sequence of integers $(n_k)$ such that $(\sin{n_k})$ is convergent.

Alternatively, as @5xum pointed out, you can proceed constructively by letting $n_k = \pi k$ so that $\sin{n_k}= 0$ which is of course convergent.

Comment: What if $(\sin n)$ were strictly decreasing, by some freak coincidence? Then there would not be a strictly increasing subsequence at all, though there may be many monotone subsequences.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I think that you've misunderstood OP's question. He is asking for an increasing sequence $(n_k)$ such that $(\sin{n_k})$ is convergent. At no point is it required that $(\sin{n_k})$ itself should be increasing.

Comment: Most probably, one is asked to find some **integer valued** such sequence $(n_j)$, see comment on main. Interestingly, the first paragraph of your post addresses this question but the "alternative" second paragraph does not at all...

Comment: If @Did is correct then this answer can be completed by showing that the set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid\sin n>\alpha\}$ is infinite for every $\alpha<1$ (and drawing conclusions). The fact that the answer is allready accepted might point in the direction that Did is wrong, but that would surprise me.

Comment: @drhab Actually the argument is already complete since it suffices to show the existence of a convergent subsequence, not necessarily of a subsequence converging to $1$. As we know, there exists subsequences converging to $1$, and even subsequences converging to $\ell$, for every $\ell$ in $[-1,1]$, but this stronger result is not needed here.

Comment: @Did You're right. I (wrongly) had in mind that $\sin(n_j)$ was demanded to be monotonically increasing as well.

Comment: @drhab I see. To prove *that*, it seems the density argument (namely, that $\mathbb Z+\pi\mathbb Z$ is dense in $\mathbb R$) is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a sequence to be convergent it does not require that the elements of the sequence are not all the same! For example, the sequence $(2,2, \dots)$ is convergent (try checking this with the definition).

Note that when we are required to prove an existential statement (there is some...) it suffices to give one example.

Note that the sine function is periodic with period $2\pi$. Note that $\sin (\pi/2) = 1$. So there are infinitely many $x$ such that $\sin (x) = 1$. Let $n_{j} := \frac{\pi}{2} + 2(j-1)\pi$ for all integers $j \geq 1$. Then the sequence $(n_{j})$ is strictly increasing and $(\sin(n_{j})) = (1,1,\dots)$ converges.

Comment: Most probably, one is asked to find some **integer valued** such sequence $(n_j)$, see comment on main.